# STM32F103RC TIM3 not working

Tags: c, timer, stm32, keil

I want to use TIM3 for controlling servos. I've already used TIM2 CH1CH2 for two servos but I need four more.The problem is that I found no PWM output in the pin.
Below is my code and I'm rather confusing about how can it be wrong as long as TIM2 is already working.Will there be any conflict? I've checked my project and am sure that I haven't used TIM3 any where else.

```
GPIO_InitTypeDef GPIO_InitStructure;
TIM_TimeBaseInitTypeDef  TIM_TimeBaseStructure;
TIM_OCInitTypeDef  TIM_OCInitStructure;

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1 | GPIO_Pin_6 | GPIO_Pin_7;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP; 
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOA, &GPIO_InitStructure);

GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Pin = GPIO_Pin_0 | GPIO_Pin_1;
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Mode = GPIO_Mode_AF_PP; 
GPIO_InitStructure.GPIO_Speed = GPIO_Speed_50MHz;
GPIO_Init(GPIOB, &GPIO_InitStructure);
TIM_DeInit(TIM2);
TIM_DeInit(TIM3);
/* Time base configuration */
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Period =  500;
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_ClockDivision =  TIM_CKD_DIV2;
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_Prescaler = 7199; // 50 Hz
TIM_TimeBaseStructure.TIM_CounterMode = TIM_CounterMode_Up;

TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM2, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);
TIM_TimeBaseInit(TIM3, &TIM_TimeBaseStructure);

/* PWM1 Mode configuration: Channel 1 */
TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCMode = TIM_OCMode_PWM1;           //produce output when counter < CCR
TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OCPolarity = TIM_OCPolarity_High;   //set "high" to be effective output
TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_Pulse = 0;                          // ccr_val
TIM_OCInitStructure.TIM_OutputState = TIM_OutputState_Enable;

TIM_OC1Init(TIM2, &TIM_OCInitStructure);
TIM_OC2Init(TIM2, &TIM_OCInitStructure);

TIM_OC1Init(TIM3, &TIM_OCInitStructure);
TIM_OC2Init(TIM3, &TIM_OCInitStructure);
TIM_OC3Init(TIM3, &TIM_OCInitStructure);
TIM_OC4Init(TIM3, &TIM_OCInitStructure);

TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM2, ENABLE);
TIM_ARRPreloadConfig(TIM3, ENABLE);

TIM_Cmd(TIM2, ENABLE);
TIM_Cmd(TIM3, ENABLE);

TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(TIM2, ENABLE);
TIM_CtrlPWMOutputs(TIM3, ENABLE);
```

Comment: Just to be sure, have you enabled the clock for TIM3 using the RCC peripheral? And of course, the clocks for GPIOA and GPIOB.

Comment: You can save everyone helping you a lot of time if you provide direct links to the documentation.

Comment: @BenVoigt http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/datasheet/CD00191185.pdf, http://www.st.com/web/catalog/mmc/FM141/SC1169/SS1031/LN1565/PF164486

Comment: @Étienne: Which is useless.  One needs the [Reference Manual for the processor family](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00171190.pdf), not the part datasheet.  Maybe also the [Programming Manual](http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/programming_manual/CD00228163.pdf).  (And having to sort through those is one reason I requested the OP to provide them)

Comment: @BenVoigt The reference manual is here, I agree with you that it is better to provide it with the question, just wanted to help: http://www.st.com/st-web-ui/static/active/en/resource/technical/document/reference_manual/CD00171190.pdf

Comment: the RCC is enabled through :RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(((uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF), ENABLE);RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(((uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF), ENABLE);

Comment: I will check the resources now. Sorry for not providing them, I'm not a native speaker of English and I'm not familiar with the manners but I will do better later on.

Answer (score 2):

Problem solved. I opened all the RCC Clock using:

```
RCC_APB1PeriphClockCmd(((uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF,ENABLE);
RCC_APB2PeriphClockCmd(((uint32_t)0xFFFFFFFF),ENABLE);
```

However there is a conflict between SPI (and some other Peripherals that I haven't verified) and TIM3 at PA6,7.
It is the conflict that caused the problem.